# Make Custom UI Element not scroll in TableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I made a custom UIPickerView and I want to have it hidden and then animate it up into the screen when a button is pressed. I usually don't have a problem with this.. I just add the view as a subview to self.view but the problem is that I'm trying to set it in a tableViewController. When I add it to self.view, it ends up just being glued to the tableviewcontroller and scrolls with the tableview... which is not what I want.
I tried adding it to self.view.window but that didn't work... I just couldn't see my custom element anywhere.

I feel like this is simple but I'm just missing something...

Comment: Why even use a UITableViewController then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your table class inherits from UITableViewController. If that's the case, adding the picker view to self.view will add it to the tableView - which is why it sticks to it. I would try to make your base class inherit from something higher than UITableViewController (UIViewController, perhaps; you can go as high as NSObject) and then give it two properties - one for the pickerView and one for the tableView. So when you add the pickerView to self.view, it would add it parallel to the table, not as its child.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want this picker to slide up the screen when needed and then disappear. there are probably a number of ways to do this, but the first thing is that it should not be a sub view of the view controller. More likely it should be a sub view of the parent view of the view controller.

I would look into the best way to side up a view, perhaps modally and then go that direction.